# billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 9 (SIGKILL) without Docker

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

```
[2021-10-27 02:05:09,365: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-5' pid:12871 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
[2021-10-27 02:05:09,412: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 9 (SIGKILL).',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eps88-epixel/.local/share/virtualenvs/multi-purpose-platform-v-13-mfAjRgrr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1267, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 9 (SIGKILL).
```

Why does Django Celery show this error in the log?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68706512/how-to-create-a-wslconfig-file